# Django Admin redirects to a looped URL

Tags: python, django, django-admin

when I'm trying to open Django admin in my project, it redirects to a weird URL that looks some kind of loop happened.
I've unregistered all models from the admin module but the problem is still the same.
at this moment there's no models added to Django admin and its URL looks like this:

```
path('admin', admin.site.urls)
```

but when I'm trying to open the admin URL (`localhost:8000/admin`), it redirects me to this URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/adminlogin/?next=/adminlogin%3Fnext%3D/adminlogin%253Fnext%253D/adminlogin%25253Fnext%25253D/adminlogin%2525253Fnext%2525253D/adminlogin%252525253Fnext%252525253D/adminlogin%25252525253Fnext%25252525253D/adminlogin%2525252525253Fnext%2525252525253D/adminlogin%252525252525253Fnext%252525252525253D/adminlogin%25252525252525253Fnext%25252525252525253D/adminlogin%2525252525252525253Fnext%2525252525252525253D/adminlogin%252525252525252525253Fnext%252525252525252525253D/adminlogin%25252525252525252525253Fnext%25252525252525252525253D/adminlogin%2525252525252525252525253Fnext%2525252525252525252525253D/adminlogin%252525252525252525252525253Fnext%252525252525252525252525253D/adminlogin%25252525252525252525252525253Fnext%25252525252525252525252525253D/adminlogin%2525252525252525252525252525253Fnext%2525252525252525252525252525253D/adminlogin%252525252525252525252525252525253Fnext%252525252525252525252525252525253D/adminlogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253Fnext%25252525252525252525252525252525253D/adminlogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253Fnext%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D/admin
```

I'm troubling with this issue for some days and couldn't find any solution! any ideas?

Comment: Can you try giving path('admin/', admin.site.urls).

Comment: it doesn't made any change

Answer (score 0):

try

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

Comment: it didn't make any difference.

Comment: in your settings,what in your values LOGIN_URL
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL,I tend to think the looping is on this parameters

Comment: both of them are even not set.